# Next-js before hydration process takes longer than other site

Tags: next.js, hydration

I'm working on a website using Next.js, and my main task is to improve its performance.

I noticed that my site's Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) is slower compared to another site (hosted on Vercel) that is also built with Next.js. I want to ensure that LCP is achieved before the hydration process in Next.js, and I'm looking for ways to make this happen and enhance the site's performance.

**My site**: 4.88seconds for LCP

[image: My site's performance]

**Vercel** : 543.43 ms for LCP

[image: Vecel's performance]